# this.setAttribute("onclick", "") Javascript doesn't works?

Tags: javascript, html

hi i have an problem when i want to execute an js code the code is like this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
   function ReplyFunc(commentid) {
       this.setAttribute("onclick", "")
       alert(commentid)
   }
</script>

<button onclick='ReplyFunc(1231);'>Reply</button>
```

nothing happening .. and not just like this code for example this code

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
   function ReplyFunc(commentid) {
       this.parentElement.innerHTML = ""
       alert(commentid)
   }
</script>

<button onclick='ReplyFunc(1231);'>Reply</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is that in the context of the function, `this` is the `window` object, not the element you click on. If you want to accomplish this with an `onclick` attribute, you will need to pass `this` as an argument to the function.

## Example:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
   function ReplyFunc(element, commentid) {
       element.setAttribute("onclick", "")
       alert(commentid)
   }
</script>

<button onclick='ReplyFunc(this, 1231);'>Reply</button>
```

This issue can also solved by using `addEventListener` and data attributes instead on `onclick`.

## Example:

```html
<button id="mybutton" data-commentid="1231">Reply</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
var mybuttonEl = document.getElementById('mybutton');
mybuttonEl.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var commentid = Number(this.getAttribute("data-commentid"));
    alert(commentid)
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some editing done:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       function ReplyFunc(commentid) {
           // this.parentElement.innerHTML = "";
           alert(commentid);
       }
    </script>
<button onclick='ReplyFunc("1231");'>Reply</button>
```

When calling the function not using "1231" will assumed to be a variable, which was not defined. Furthermore, ending lines with semicolons in javascript is needed for right interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `setAttribute()` to update the "onclick" property. Set it as a property directly on the target object.

```
function ReplyFunc(commentid) {
   this.onclick = null;
   alert(commentid)
}
```

In addition, you'll have to arrange for `this` to refer to the target:

```
<button onclick="ReplyFunc.call(this, 1234)">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

use addEventListener

```
var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];

button.addEventListener('click', handler);

function handler(e) {
    console.log('event', e);
    button.removeEventListener('click', handler);
}
```